# Total amount of times a link is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, click

Okay so I have a link that is directed to one website example:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com">Click me!</a>
```

So what I want to chnage the href link after the 10th time that is clicked to a different location what ive done is flawed becase it only counts the number of times the link has been clicked since the last reload ex:

```
var count = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
count++;
if(count > 10){
$('a').attr("href","https://www.yahoo.com");
}
});
});
```

So i need a counter that keeps track of the total times its been clicked not just the times after the page reloads. It needs to keep track of every click from every user because so i dont think cookies would work i may be wrong.

Comment: use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Comment: Cookie stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Answer (score 3):

You need to preserve the value in a cookie/local storage to retain the value across multiple sessions. You can use a library like [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to make the cookie operations easy

Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function () {
        var count = parseInt($.cookie('link-count'), 10) || 0
        count++;
        if (count > 10) {
            $('a').attr("href", "https://www.yahoo.com");
        }
        $.cookie('link-count', count)
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D9gmc/1/) - click on the link and refresh the page the counter will retain the value

Comment: how exacly do i do that?

Comment: thats a lot to ask in one question. Perhaps you should do some research on creating and storing cookies first

Comment: Note that this is not very practical once you have multiple links that should be tracked separately.

Comment: @Jack depends on how may has to be tracked - each of the link should have a unique cookie

Comment: That's even worse; all those cookies are sent to the server each time as well, making them even more useless baggage :)

Comment: @Jack that why I said depends on how many - it can be done for 1/2 items at max - more than that a server side storage should be considered (not localStorage because IE support)

Comment: Interim solution might be to JSON encode the cookie so that it can contain multiple counters :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a cookie you can save the state and later read it and use it.

With jQuery it is very easy to use cookies.

```
 $.cookie("var", "10");
```